# include a config file in webpack bundle

Tags: node.js, webpack

In my webpack project I want to bundle my project and include an example usage file with it. However when I bundle my project in this form

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.js',
    about: './src/pages/config.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'report' //makes this a global variable we can call from basic javascript page,
devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    clientLogLevel: 'none',
    stats: 'errors-only'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] //npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({ cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'ESS Map Learning',
    }),
  ],
};
  },
```

The outputted file in the dist is converted or loaded into bundled code and is unreadable as an example. I am trying to find a way to load this file so it is not changed and sits in the bundle in its original format

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve?

Comment: when I try to bundle my 'example' file which is just some commented out code explaining how to use the program, which people using the program will need as an explanation, it is converted into bundle.js style code which is obviously not in a readable form. I want to output it so it just remains how it is originally typed

Comment: You mean you're keen to keep the comments for your code, don't you? Can you also share full `webpack.config.js` file?

Comment: the about page is entire page that I want to remain in the exact form. It really could be a txt file

Comment: sounds like building with `mode: development` would fit your need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include an example usage file along with your bundle, you can try the following two ways:

### 1. use CopyWebpackPlugin

With this plugin, you can copy specific files from your source project into your output folder.

First you need to install the plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin
```

Then in your webpack configuration file:

```js
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: "path/to/some-example.js",
        to: ""  // leave blank if you want to keep the folder hierachy as in the source code, otherwise specify an output path
      },
    ]),
  ]
}
```

More about the plugin:

- [Webpack Plugins: CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin)

### 2. use the "Asset Modules" configuration

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /example\.js/,     // regex to match your source example file path
        type: 'asset/resource',  // files with this type will be copied to your output folder
        generator: {
          filename: 'examples/[name][ext]',    // you can give a desired name for your output file, or webpack will defaultly name it with hash value
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // rest of your webpack configuration
  // ...
}
```

Caveats: I think webpack will never process your example file if it is not a dependency of any of your entry points (which is very likely the case). In this sense I guess using the CopyWebpackPlugin is more reliable.

More about asset modules:

- [Webpack Guides: Asset Management](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/)
- [Webpack Guides: Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)